# Linux, Wine for unity environment

Tags: unity, wine, desktop-environments, environment

How can i download wine on a unity desktop environment? I've been trying to do so by using commands i found online but nothing helps. I found it easy to download it in xfce4, but now im using unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. Fire up a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

That should do it!

---

If you want to get the latest development version, you'll have to uninstall any previously installed version and use an external PPA:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```